# JSON.parse throws Unexpected token

Tags: json

why would this string throw error in JSON.parse

```
[{"name":"listName","readonly":false,"value":"list"},{"name":"showHeader","readonly":true,"value":false},{"name":"showBorder","readonly":true,"value":false},{"name":"transparent","readonly":true,"value":true},{"name":"showTitle","readonly":false,"value":false},{"name":"showDesc","readonly":false,"value":false},{"name":"showMods","readonly":false,"value":false},{"name":"showTools","readonly":false,"value":true}]
```

This is the code. the above string is returned via AJAX as widgetInstance.data

```
if ($scope.widgetInstance.widgetId == 6)
            {
                $scope.widgetData = JSON.parse($scope.widgetInstance.data);

            } else {
                $scope.widgetData = JSON.parse($scope.widgetInstance.dataSanitized);
            }
```

Comment: it is valid json so you must be doing something wrong in your code

Comment: You need to show more code. Are you sure `$scope.widgetInstance.widgetId == 6`? What is `$scope.widgetInstance.dataSanitized`?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem once in java while I tried to parse a json object decrypted with an RSA key. Because of the padding, the decrpytion had result in many trailing "\0" at the end of the string. This leads to the json parser error. Perhaps you are in the same trouble?